# Which is better between "Friends you have more, more powerful you became" and "More friends you have, more power you will will have"?

Tags: comparative-constructions

I want to say if you have more friend, you will be more powerful.

Which one is better in form?

- Friends you have more, more powerful you became
- More friends you have, more power you will will have

Does the above options correct?

Comment: The more friends you have, the more power you will have.

Comment: The first one is a bit 'Yoda' ...but it's always 'the more' for this type of comparison, so as @JayHook said, or 'The more friends you have, the more powerful you [will] become.'

Answer (score 1):

As @JayHook said,

> The more friends you have, the more power you will have.

Is correct.

Some alternatives are:

> The more friends you get, the more powerful you will become.
>
> When you have friends, you have power (slightly different meaning)
>
> Friends are power. (more-than-slightly different meaning)

Hope this helps.